# Find substring divided by slashes

Tags: c#, regex

I need to find the substring that starts with a slash symbol and ends with a slash symbol.

```
string sourceStr = "assets/Level 1/diffuse;
```

The output of the regex must be *"**Level 1**"*

I found this regex `^"\"(.+)"\"$` but it seems like it doesn't works the way I wanted.
Any ideas?

Comment: Is .split('/') not an option here?

Comment: Instead of the lazy dot star, I'd recommend: `@"(?<=/)[^/]+(?=/)"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need regex for that. Just an old-school `.Split()` would be enough

Just do this:

```
string sourceStr = "assets/Level 1/diffuse";
var subStr = sourceStr.Split('/')[1];
Console.WriteLine(subStr); // Level 1
```

Comment: +1.  Better to avoid regular expressions if possible.

Comment: This would not match all values starting and ending with a /, ie. a/b/c/d  both b and c would fall within the paramater of starting and ending with a /, the code above would only find b

Comment: @JensB, let OP ask for it. I'm helping OP and my answer is just fine :)

Comment: @JensB I think the point is that a regular expression is superfluous here.  You could easily expand this to serve whatever purpose you require.  Removing the ends of an array called with "Split" and afterwards calling Join("/") would perform the same purpose.

Comment: Your solution satisfied me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Netherwire, glad to have helped you `:)`

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] sourceStrSplit = sourceStr.Split('/');

for(int i=1; i< sourceStrSplit.Length-1; i++)
{
   //All the sourceStrSplit[i] is what you required.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A though on how to make this work with any number of slashes so that only items contained inside two slashes are returned

https://dotnetfiddle.net/ErN9Wu

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.Write("1 -> ");
    foreach(var w in getStringsInsideSlashes("a/b"))
        Console.Write(w + " - ");
    Console.WriteLine("");

    Console.Write("2 -> ");
    foreach(var w in getStringsInsideSlashes("a/b/c"))
        Console.Write(w + " - ");
    Console.WriteLine("");

    Console.Write("3 -> ");
    foreach(var w in getStringsInsideSlashes("a/b/c/d"))
        Console.Write(w + " - ");
    Console.WriteLine("");

    Console.Write("4 -> ");
    foreach(var w in getStringsInsideSlashes("a/b/c/d/"))
        Console.Write(w + " - ");
    Console.WriteLine("");

}

public static string[] getStringsInsideSlashes(string a){
    return a.Split('/').Skip(1).Take(a.Split('/').Count() -2).ToArray<string>();    
}
```

Output

```
1 -> 
2 -> b - 
3 -> b - c - 
4 -> b - c - d -
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of RegEx you can use String split function.

```
string strTestline = "This is /Test/. You can /test2/";
string[] strarray = strTestline.Split(new char[] { '/' });

foreach (string block in strarray)
{
     Console.WriteLine(block);
}
```